# How to convert a Swift array to a tuple in a single line?

Tags: swift, tuples

How to convert a Swift array into a tuple in single line? Is it possible to do using map?

```
let arr = [1, 2]

let (a, b) = tuple(arr)  #tuple method doesn't exits, how can it be achieved
```

Comment: Does `let (a, b) = (arr[0], arr[1])` not cut it?

Comment: @Hamish what happens if array is big?

Comment: Then you most likely shouldn't be working with tuples – why do you need a tuple in the first place?